# How to obtain p95 of a day and p95 of the last 7 days of that day from Clickhouse through an SQL query?

Tags: clickhouse

Now, my code is:

```
select
       toStartOfDay(time_stamp) as day,
       quantileExact(0.95)(duration) as p95,
       '' as day7_p95 --what code?
from
     duration_all
where
      time_stamp >= '2022-03-03 00:00:00' and
      time_stamp <= '2022-03-09 00:00:00'
group by toStartOfDay(time_stamp)
order by toStartOfDay(time_stamp)
```

the output is:

[image]

but I can only get the p95 of every day, and I don't know how to modify the above SQL to get the p95 of nearly 7 days every day.

Comment: I have not come across quantileExact and don't really want to know what it does but adding sample raw data and expected outcome would help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    day,
    finalizeAggregation(0.95)(state) AS p95,
    quantileExactMerge(0.95)(state) OVER (ORDER BY day ASC Rows BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS day7_p95
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toStartOfDay(time_stamp) AS day,
        quantileExactState(0.95)(val) AS state
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            now() - (number * 3600) AS time_stamp,
            (rand() % 33333) / 10000 AS val
        FROM numbers(500)
    )
    GROUP BY day
    ORDER BY day ASC
)

Query id: ad35a361-730e-4860-99ce-35e88a076a45

┌─────────────────day─┬────p95─┬─day7_p95─┐
│ 2022-02-19 00:00:00 │ 3.2733 │   3.2733 │
│ 2022-02-20 00:00:00 │ 3.1988 │   3.2079 │
│ 2022-02-21 00:00:00 │ 3.0383 │   3.1988 │
│ 2022-02-22 00:00:00 │ 2.9919 │   3.1988 │
│ 2022-02-23 00:00:00 │ 3.1512 │   3.1988 │
│ 2022-02-24 00:00:00 │ 3.0554 │   3.1512 │
│ 2022-02-25 00:00:00 │ 2.9619 │   3.1362 │
│ 2022-02-26 00:00:00 │ 3.3009 │   3.1783 │
│ 2022-02-27 00:00:00 │ 2.9855 │   3.1512 │
│ 2022-02-28 00:00:00 │ 3.0934 │   3.1266 │
│ 2022-03-01 00:00:00 │ 3.2075 │    3.174 │
│ 2022-03-02 00:00:00 │ 3.1238 │    3.174 │
│ 2022-03-03 00:00:00 │  3.319 │   3.1783 │
│ 2022-03-04 00:00:00 │ 2.9233 │   3.1783 │
│ 2022-03-05 00:00:00 │ 3.1928 │   3.1857 │
│ 2022-03-06 00:00:00 │ 3.1941 │   3.1857 │
│ 2022-03-07 00:00:00 │ 3.0741 │   3.1857 │
│ 2022-03-08 00:00:00 │ 3.1022 │   3.1857 │
│ 2022-03-09 00:00:00 │ 2.9859 │   3.1238 │
│ 2022-03-10 00:00:00 │ 3.1898 │   3.1446 │
│ 2022-03-11 00:00:00 │ 2.7417 │   3.1222 │
│ 2022-03-12 00:00:00 │ 3.2549 │   3.1898 │
└─────────────────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```