# Count in time window for each present day in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with logs of users who used certain service. Something like the table below, each row is timestamp of activity and user id.

| user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 831 | 2022-06-22 04:37:10 |
| 789 | 2022-06-22 12:38:57 |
| 831 | 2022-06-22 16:40:10 |

I want to calculate number of unique users in each day, but not just in that day, but include a week prior. Basically, moving window unique count: for day "x" count should be in window of "x-7 days":"x".

As I see in docs,

> INTERVAL syntax for DateTime RANGE OFFSET frame: not supported, specify the number of seconds instead (RANGE works with any numeric type).

easy way of using interval with passing something like `RANGE INTERVAL 7 day PRECEDING` is not supported, and they suggest to use range with passing seconds, but I don't really have experience with range in sql, so I don't really get how do you pass seconds there. My current code:

```
with cleaned_table as (
  select
    user_id,
    date_trunc('day', timestamp) as day
  from
    table
)
SELECT
  day,
  uniqExact(user_id) OVER (
    PARTITION by day ORDER BY day range ???
  )
FROM
  cleaned_table
```

Also, ideally, I have a feeling that I should add `group by` somewhere since I need only one row per each day, not a row for each row in initial table, and without grouping I'm doing recalculation(?) for each row instead of calculating for each day once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
create table t(user_id Int64, timestamp DateTime) Engine = Memory as select * from values((831, '2022-06-22 04:37:10'), (789,'2022-06-22 12:38:57'), (831,'2022-06-22 16:40:10'), (1,'2022-06-21 12:38:57'), (2,'2022-06-20 16:40:10'));


SELECT
    day,
    finalizeAggregation(u) AS uniqByDay,
    uniqMerge(u) OVER (ORDER BY day ASC RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS uniqBy6Days
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toDate(timestamp) AS day,
        uniqState(user_id) AS u
    FROM t
    GROUP BY day
)
ORDER BY day ASC

┌────────day─┬─uniqByDay─┬─uniqBy6Days─┐
│ 2022-06-20 │         1 │           1 │
│ 2022-06-21 │         1 │           2 │
│ 2022-06-22 │         2 │           4 │
└────────────┴───────────┴─────────────┘
```

see [How to obtain p95 of a day and p95 of the last 7 days of that day from Clickhouse through an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434197/how-to-obtain-p95-of-a-day-and-p95-of-the-last-7-days-of-that-day-from-clickhous/71445056#71445056)

Answer (score 0):

I'll mark this as an answer, but I'd be happy if anyone knows how to optimize this solution by incorporating `group by` or other methods to not recalculate window function for each row and calculate it only once for each day.

Anyway, `RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING and current row` is what I was searching for, worked just fine. Also added `::date` to cast timestamp into date dtype, and `DISTINCT day` allows directly picking only one row for each day instead of running `group by` with `any` one more time.

```
with cleaned_table as (
  select
    user_id,
    date_trunc('day', timestamp)::date as day
  from
    table
)

SELECT
  DISTINCT day,
  uniqExact(user_id) OVER (
    ORDER BY
      day ASC RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING
      and current row
  ) as users
FROM
  cleaned_table
```